Why GitVersion is not incrementing major number when merge from releases branch
I am following a simple github branching strategy and seeing some weird results.
I have GitVersion.yml as:
next-version: 1.0.0
mode: MainLine
assembly-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatch
assembly-file-versioning-scheme: MajorMinorPatchTag
increment: Inherit
continuous-delivery-fallback-tag: ci
tag-prefix: '[vV]'
major-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(breaking|major)'
minor-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(feature|minor)'
patch-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(fix|patch)'
no-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(none|skip)'
legacy-semver-padding: 4
build-metadata-padding: 4
commits-since-version-source-padding: 4
commit-message-incrementing: Enabled
commit-date-format: 'yyyy-MM-dd'
branches:
  master:
    tag: ''
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    increment: Patch
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^master
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: false
  release:
    mode: ContinuousDelivery
    tag: beta
    increment: Major
    prevent-increment-of-merged-branch-version: true
    track-merge-target: false
    regex: ^releases?[/-]
    tracks-release-branches: false
    is-release-branch: true
    pre-release-weight: 1000

I created a branch "releases/er" and did some commits. I am under expectation that any commit to "releases/er" should bump major. But i see no change. Below is the log.
dotnet-gitversion:
{
  "Major": 1,
  "Minor": 0,
  "Patch": 0,
  "PreReleaseTag": "beta.1",
  "PreReleaseTagWithDash": "-beta.1",
  "PreReleaseLabel": "beta",
  "PreReleaseLabelWithDash": "-beta",
  "PreReleaseNumber": 1,
  "WeightedPreReleaseNumber": 1001,
  "BuildMetaData": 2,
  "BuildMetaDataPadded": "0002",
  "FullBuildMetaData": "2.Branch.releases-er.Sha.77cb0f510fe4edc5bfc69c6ce76f16f9ed924f42",
  "MajorMinorPatch": "1.0.0",
  "SemVer": "1.0.0-beta.1",
  "LegacySemVer": "1.0.0-beta1",
  "LegacySemVerPadded": "1.0.0-beta0001",
  "AssemblySemVer": "1.0.0.0",
  "AssemblySemFileVer": "1.0.0.1",
  "FullSemVer": "1.0.0-beta.1+2",
  "InformationalVersion": "1.0.0-beta.1+2.Branch.releases-er.Sha.77cb0f510fe4edc5bfc69c6ce76f16f9ed924f42",
  "BranchName": "releases/er",
  "EscapedBranchName": "releases-er",
  "Sha": "77cb0f510fe4edc5bfc69c6ce76f16f9ed924f42",
  "ShortSha": "77cb0f5",
  "NuGetVersionV2": "1.0.0-beta0001",
  "NuGetVersion": "1.0.0-beta0001",
  "NuGetPreReleaseTagV2": "beta0001",
  "NuGetPreReleaseTag": "beta0001",
  "VersionSourceSha": "00f6e4a646173c2a866d81cebab96004cb31f34c",
  "CommitsSinceVersionSource": 2,
  "CommitsSinceVersionSourcePadded": "0002",
  "UncommittedChanges": 0,
  "CommitDate": "2024-10-16"
}

Now if I commit directly on master branch, I still see no change in patch number. Below is the log.
dotnet-gitversion
{
  "Major": 1,
  "Minor": 0,
  "Patch": 0,
  "PreReleaseTag": "2",
  "PreReleaseTagWithDash": "",
  "PreReleaseLabel": "",
  "PreReleaseLabelWithDash": "",
  "PreReleaseNumber": null,
  "WeightedPreReleaseNumber": 60000,
  "BuildMetaData": null,
  "BuildMetaDataPadded": "",
  "FullBuildMetaData": "Branch.master.Sha.92a8e843c062e107039f11831f71cfe708f04e63",
  "MajorMinorPatch": "1.0.0",
  "SemVer": "1.0.0",
  "LegacySemVer": "1.0.0",
  "LegacySemVerPadded": "1.0.0",
  "AssemblySemVer": "1.0.0.0",
  "AssemblySemFileVer": "1.0.0.2",
  "FullSemVer": "1.0.0",
  "InformationalVersion": "1.0.0+Branch.master.Sha.92a8e843c062e107039f11831f71cfe708f04e63",
  "BranchName": "master",
  "EscapedBranchName": "master",
  "Sha": "92a8e843c062e107039f11831f71cfe708f04e63",
  "ShortSha": "92a8e84",
  "NuGetVersionV2": "1.0.0",
  "NuGetVersion": "1.0.0",
  "NuGetPreReleaseTagV2": "",
  "NuGetPreReleaseTag": "",
  "VersionSourceSha": "9f8207ea011f32ed250ccd1ab14cf559e8ffb584",
  "CommitsSinceVersionSource": 2,
  "CommitsSinceVersionSourcePadded": "0002",
  "UncommittedChanges": 0,
  "CommitDate": "2024-10-16"
}

The rules are already set that commit to master should bump patch while releases/* should bump Major

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
